# How to call and get JSON value on time interval?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page and it contains a json string.Form another page I need to use ajax call and read that value every 3 second and display in page.I was able to achieve everything except calling to the page on interval.I can see that ajax call is working but new values are not receiving to my page.Here is my code.

```
<? $url = 'http://mydomain.com/test';?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>  
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    myjsonval();   
});

function myjsonval(){

    var jsonp = '[<? echo file_get_contents($url);?>]';
    var lang = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    $.each(obj, function() {
        lang += this['precentage'] + "<br/>";
    });
    $('span').html(lang);
     console.log('test called');
    setTimeout(myjsonval, 3000);

}
        </script>
<span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

when I refresh my page using F5 new value is showing.But I need to get the value automatically via AJAX call.Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You mixed up PHP and javascript. The PHP read the file for once when the client loads the page and won't read it again. So your function is actually reading the same json string over and over again. You can do what you want with ajax.

Comment: So what is your point me to change something in this code to achieve it?

Comment: Take a look at this first: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @DanielCheng is correct. Additionally, you'll need to call `setTimeout(myjsonval, 3000);` recursively, or `setInterval(myjsonval, 3000)` and `clearInterval()` when done.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    myjsonval();   
    setInterval(myjsonval, 3000);
 });
```

Also remove modify your function myjsonval like:

```
  function myjsonval(){

var jsonp = '[<? echo file_get_contents($url);?>]';
var lang = '';
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
$.each(obj, function() {
    lang += this['precentage'] + "<br/>";
});
$('span').html(lang);
 console.log('test called');
```

}

Comment: I don't think this solves any problem. The jsonp is still the same jsonp.

Comment: Yes true.But this code I can make request to server in every 3 second.
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://mydomain.com/test", function myj() {
 
alert( "success" );
 setInterval(myj, 3000);
})

But I dont understand where should I put this?